# Commands inside square bracket calls

Tags: luatex

Apologies if I'm not using the correct vocabulary here.

I'm currently using Polyglossia in my tex file. To set the main language, I use:

```
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
```

I'd like to break out both the language and variant into variables that I can change elsewhere, so I modify the code to become:

```
\newcommand{\customlang}{english}
\newcommand{\customlangvariant}{usmax}

\setmainlanguage[variant=\customlangvariant]{\customlang}
```

Except this time, when I build, I get the error

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Unknown English variant `usmax' on input line 125.
```

Obviously `usmax` is a correct variant, so there's something fundamental that I'm missing here when it comes to calling the `\setmainlanguage` command. Using `\customlang` seems to work, but `\customlangvariant` doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Windows 10, LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)

Comment: When values for keys are absorbed, they're not touched in any way, so Polyglossia is right in telling you that it doesn't know the `\customvariant` variant; it's only because of how error messages are displayed that `usmax` is able to sneak in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When values for keys are absorbed, no interpretation is made.

Thus Polyglossia is right in telling you that it doesn't know the variant `\customlangvariant`, because it is different from the only accepted ones, which are

```
uk british us american usmax australian newzealand canadian
```

You get a puzzling error message because Polyglossia passes `\customlangvariant` to the error management of LaTeX, which eventually will expand it into `usmax`.

I'm not sure you really gain something with that approach. But, if you want, you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newcommand{\customlang}{english}
\newcommand{\customlangvariant}{usmax}

\expandafter\setmainlanguage\expanded{[variant=\customlangvariant]}{\customlang}

\begin{document}

x

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! And thanks for the explanation. To answer your question on what I'm gaining with the approach; the code provided was for clarity - the variables are passed in with a Pandoc build call